# GPU pass-through KVM Fedora 23

Tags: linux, fedora, kvm

I am attempting to pass a GPU to a windows 10 VM running on a Fedora 23 host:

Virt-manager
Host: Fedora 23
Guest: Windows 10 64 bit guest UEFI OVMF
GPU: R7 AMD Radon 250 is the GPU that I am attempting to pass to a VM

Both VT-x and VT-d are supported by the processor i7-5960X

I followed a guide from here:
https://bluehatrecord.wordpress.com/...ith-fedora-22/

Now everything works out fine but when I boot the windows VM and attempt to install a driver that I got from here:
http://support.amd.com/en-us/downloa...indows+10+-+64

The windows VM just reboots and nothing happens
The windows VM also sees the PCI device but it is lacking drivers for it which I can not install as they cause the machine to reboot.

The goal is to make a Windows gaming machine as a VM on Linux host and I really do not wish to be dual booting. The project goal is to have this or similar set up function.

Comment: Here is a good blog on topic: http://vfio.blogspot.ru/2015/05/vfio-gpu-how-to-series-part-1-hardware.html (this is the link to the first part, read all posts of that guy since May '15) Remember, that you really need to install libvirt from virtpreview repository as this blog states. I personally succeeded to run 6 290 Radeons within a VM running Win10 with AMD drivers.

Comment: I checked it out but at the moement as far as I can see there are not boot problems but I get a black screen

Comment: Okay so I have manage to confirm my original suspicions, that the driver of the AMD is causing the problem somehow.
To confirm this and that the motherboard is capable I borrowed an nvidia gtx strix asus 970 from a friend and managed to pass it and it works without bigger problems. 

Now for the AMD card R7 250 I just cannot get this to work at all, even though people are reporting that this card works in this setup. The AMD driver just restarts the virtual machine of windows and it is not installed.